# Can't See Custom uibarbuttonitem at Right side of navigation bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, rightbarbuttonitem

I am trying to add custom navigation bar button at right side of navigation bar.

here is my code.

```
UIButton *customPrintButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[customPrintButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30)];
[customPrintButton.titleLabel setTextColor:[appDelegate getAppPinkColor]];
[customPrintButton setTitle:@"Print" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[customPrintButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[customPrintButton setExclusiveTouch:YES];
[customPrintButton.titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[customPrintButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20]];
[customPrintButton addTarget:self action:@selector(printOutButton_Clicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

printOutBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:customPrintButton];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = printOutBtn;
```

but still i can't see the button on my page..

Comment: Is your viewController in a navigationController and the navigationController's navigationBarHidden is NO?

Comment: definitely this code will work you have done something wrong in some other...

Comment: Verify frame of your view controller. Check Width of your controller as well as width of your navigation bar.

Comment: Are you sure your `[appDelegate getAppPinkColor]` is valid? Did you try changing the parameter for `setTextColor:`? Something like, `[UIColor redColor]`;

Comment: @GenieWanted is right because i checked your code in my pc and it is showing me button

Comment: Try making your button's frame a bit narrower. Also, I assume `self.navigationItem` is a valid navigation item?

Comment: Your code works just fine for me when I add it to 'viewDidLoad'. Where do you add it?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add title color..

that's why default it takes white color as text color

Thanks for reply.